# how to let "mvn compile" includes "provided" scope dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

I realize that when I build the jar locally, the "provided" dependencies aren't get included, and so the jar is not executable.

how to let "mvn compile" includes "provided" scope dependencies?

Comment: Please explain more detail what you mean by "build the jar". The _standard_ process is for jars to include only their own code and not dependencies; if you're trying to build a "fat jar", include the configuration you have to do so.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sorry I am not sure what the right term is. I meant build a jar so I can run java -jar xx.jar to execute it

Comment: That's called a "fat jar" (meaning that all of the dependencies are _copied into_ the jar; the normal result is to only include the classes that you defined in your own code and to add the other jars to the classpath independently).

Answer (score 2):

Change your "provided" dependencies to "compile" dependencies.  Since it's the default scope, remove the scope tag in the dependency.

To quote [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope), emphasis mine:

> - compile This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>   Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
>   provided
> - This is much like `compile`, but **indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime**. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. A
>   dependency with this scope is **added to the classpath used for
>   compilation and test**, but **not the runtime classpath**. It is not
>   transitive.

In short:  a dependency that is marked as "provided" isn't included in your build because, by declaring it as provided, you are telling Maven that it does not have to include it in your build because something else *is*.